# What's wrong with this MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Having this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ShowPage",
    "default.aspx/{page}/{pagetype}",
    new {
        controller = "Info",
        action = "PageASPX",
        page = "emptypage",
        pagetype = "emptypagetype"
    }
);
```

To catch `default.aspx?page=order` 
(I need to generate a permanet redirect fom the old site to my new MVC site)

The route is matched as I can see in route debugger, but I don't get any values in the route

```
Key          Value
page         emptypage 
pagetype     emptypagetype 
controller   Info 
action       PageASPX
```

What's wrong??

Comment: Perhabs, your request has been caught by another MapRoute?

Comment: did you try: `default.aspx/order`? Because that's what your route defines. And for permanent redirects it better to use **IIS Rewrite** module instead of mangling with your routes in your app. It also makes sense to not keep legacy app requirements in new application anywhere else than business requirements.

Comment: Can you also show us your `PageASPX()` controller action signature?

Comment: Nope - I omly get match on that route and I can see in the view, that it's going the right way.

Comment: And I don't want to use iis rewrite.

Comment: Controller action signature?

Comment: This?
True default.aspx/{page}/{pagetype} controller = Info, action = SideASPX, page = emptypage, pagetype = emptypagetype

Comment: That's route definition and not controller action... Check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC route definitions have URL segments. Your route looks like this:

```
default.aspx/{page}/{pagetype}
```

this means that requests like `default.aspx/order` should populate `page` value during route resolution because it's provided as a URL segment. This doesn't mean that `page` won't get populated later on when model binding occurs and your controller action gets invoked.

If your controller action signature seems similar to this:

```
public ActionResult PageASPX(string page, string pagetype)
{
    ...
}
```

Those two parameters may still get populated even when you'd provide them as query variables and not URL segments. The only requirement is that **routing doesn't provide default values for missing segment values** (or they're set as optional). Default MVC model binder will then populate `page` action parameter with actual query variable value.

So the main thing is that you should change your routing definition (see last section of my answer).

### Requests that should work

In order for your routing to recognise `page` and `pagetype` URL segment variables your requests should look like this:

```
default.aspx/somepage
default.aspx/somepage/sometype
```

Provided that your routing doesn't define defaults for `page` and `pagetype` then your controller actions will get `page` and `pagetype` parameters populated with correct values when your requests look like:

```
default.aspx/somepage
default.aspx/somepage/sometype
default.aspx?page=somepage
default.aspx?pagetype=sometype
default.aspx?page=somepage&pagetype=sometype
```

### Mixing route values and query string variables

As my tests show Asp.net MVC doesn't provide route value overriding when it has a value (either provided in the URL itself as segment or as route defaults). In your case if you'd request this URL:

```
default.aspx/routepage?page=querypage
```

your action method would see `page` parameter to have value of *routepage*. **Always**.

The more important aspect of this is that **when you provide default value in route definition itself, you won't be able to set it as a query string at all even when you omit it from the URL**. To avoid this issue, you have two choices:

1. set `page` and `pagetype` as `UrlParameter.Optional` which will allow you to override their values with query string variables when URL won't have them - this means that you can always use only URL segments or query strings, but not both, because URL segments prevails
2. have different names for URL segment variables and query string variables - the downside is that you'd need to have your action with double parameters which is undesired:

   ```
   public ActionResult PageASPX(string routePage, string routeType, string queryPage, string queryType)
   {
       string page = routePage ?? queryPage ?? string.Empty;
       string type = routeType ?? queryType ?? string.Emtpy;
       ...
   }
   ```

### Best solution

Change your routing so you have separate routing definition for variables provided as URL segments and another for variables provided as query string variables. Then wire these routes to the same controller action as long as all variables (in segments and query string) share the same names:

```
route.MapRoute(
    "InSegmentsBoth",
    "default.aspx/{page}/{pagetype}",
    new { controller = "Info", action = "PageASPX" }
);
route.MapRoute(
    "InSegmentsPage",
    "default.aspx/{page}",
    new { controller = Info"", action = "PageASPX" }
);
route.MapRoute(
    "InQueryString",
    "default.aspx",
    new { controller = "Info", action = "PageASPX" }
);
```

If your requests provide both values (segments and query variables) as in

```
default.aspx/segmentpage?page=querypage
```

then segment values have precedence so action parameter `page` will have value of *segmentpage* for this request.

Comment: Nope. Haveing `public ActionResult PageASPX(string page, string pagetype)
        {
            ViewBag.pagetype = pagetype;
            return View();
        }`

And showing the pagetype in the view gives emptypagetype

Comment: @ThorOstergaard: Of course it does, because all you've set was `page`, but not `pagetype`. `pagetype`'s value is still the one defined by your routing. And you didn't override that using query variable.

Comment: @ThorOstergaard: What value would you like to pass it over to the view? Check my edited answer that may shed some light on the situation. I think you don't understand completely how MVC works or you're not making yourself clear what the problem is?

Comment: I'm just passing the value to the view for testing

Comment: make a request to: `default.aspx?page=something&pagetype=otherthing`. You should see correct values in your view, right?

Comment: nope. Now having `routes.MapRoute(
             "ShowPage",
              "default.aspx/{pagetype}",
              new { controller="Info", action="PageASPX", pagetype="emptypagetype" }
             );`

And testing `default.aspx?pagetype=order`

But still gets emptypagetype in my view.

Comment: @ThorOstergaard: Ok I got to the problem. When you set default routing values they can't be overridden by query strings. If you set your `page` and  `pagetype` route variables to be `UrlParameter.Optional` then query string variables would populate them as expected.

Comment: @ThorOstergaard: I've managed to resolve your problem. Check my edited answer. I've tested it myself and it works.

Comment: @ThorOstergaard: I've made my final edits to my answer. I removed route constraints because they're not needed since defaults aren't provided and I edited body of the answer a bit to not have misleading information. **Thank you for asking this question**, because I thought MVC allowed overriding of segment values by providing query string variables. Therefore +1 on your question.